# C# - Linq to SQL , type conversion error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, types

new to LINQ & would like to know why the error & best way to resolve.

I am getting, 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)' error

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("audi a2");
names.Add("audi a4");

List<string> result1 = new List<string>();

result1=(from name in names
         where name.Contains("a2")
         select name);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of the from is an IEnumerable, you need to create a list to hold it.

```
result1=(from name in names
                    where name.Contains("a2")
                    select name).ToList();
```

so you can simply:

```
List<string> result1 = (from name in names
                                 where name.Contains("a2")
                                 select name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Throw on .ToList() at the end of your Linq query.

```
result1=(from name in names
     where name.Contains("a2")
     select name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using Linq's function syntax:

```
result1 = names.where(x => x.Contains("a2")).ToList();
```

Comment: read it as where (for each item (x) in names run the test x.Contains(...)

Comment: @Obalix - great answer, u did it in 1 line! that's pretty cool.